# How to replace param "t" to "className"?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, intellij-idea

```
Android Studio 3.2.1
Kotlin plugin version 1.3.11-release-Studio3.2-1
ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.11' 
RxJava 1.3.0
```

For example when I type in `*.kt` file: `Observable.unsafeCreate{}` and then press `Ctrl+Space` between `{}` , then IntellijIdea suggest me to type symbol `t ->`, but when I do the same in `.java` file result is `subscriber ->` :

`*.kt` **file:**

```
fun anyFunc(): Observable<Boolean>{
    return Observable.unsafeCreate { t -> t }
}
```

[image]

`*.java` **file:**

```
public void anyFunc() {
    Observable.unsafeCreate(subscriber -> {});
}
```

How to make in Kotlin file the same behavior of suggestion typing like in Java file?

---

**[UPDATE]**
Seems it is because of `call()` method in `rx.functions.Func1`, it has param `t`:

```
public interface Func1<T, R> extends Function { 
    R call(T t); 
}
```

Comment: In Java, you have to provide a name for the lambda argument whereas in Kotlin, there's an implicit name `it` for single arguments in lambdas. You can simply say `unsafeCreate { it }`

Comment: @s1m0nw1 I know about `it` too. But I want `className`. This will be more understandable to read and after quick looking on code

Comment: What version of Android Studio, RxJava are you using?

Comment: @NickUnuchek - Is this your question? https://www.developerfaqs.com/5967/how-to-replace-param-t-to-classname It appears to have an answer on developerfaqs.com.

Answer (score 5):

I'm using

> **Android Studio 3.2.1**,
>
> **rxjava:2.2.0**,
>
> **Kotlin plugin version 1.3.11-release-Studio3.2-1**

After typing in `*.kt` file: `Observable.unsafeCreate{}` and pressing **Ctrl+Space** between `{}` Android Studio shows me next suggestion:

[image]

The same suggestion Android Studio shows when I'm typing in `*.java` file.

I didn't make any configuration changes in Android Studio Preferences.

I guess you are importing `Observable` from `rx` - the first item in the completion list on the image below. Try to import `Observable` from `io.reactivex` - highlighted item in the completion list below, it may help: `import io.reactivex.Observable`.

[image]

To use it you need to import rxjava2:

```
implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.0'
```

**EDIT**:

As was figured out code completion dialog showed `t ->` because parameter in `Action1.call(T t)` called `t`. We can see it if we look at the signature of `rx.Observable.unsafeCreate` method in **RxJava 1.3**:

```
public static <T> Observable<T> unsafeCreate(OnSubscribe<T> f) {
    return new Observable<T>(RxJavaHooks.onCreate(f));
}
```

`OnSubscribe` interface extends `Action1<Subscriber<? super T>`, and `Action1` has next signature:

```
public interface Action1<T> extends Action {
    void call(T t);
}
```

So parameter is called `t` and Android Studio suggests it as `t ->`.

In **RxJava2** we have different signature:

```
public static <T> Observable<T> unsafeCreate(ObservableSource<T> onSubscribe) {...}

public interface ObservableSource<T> {
    void subscribe(@NonNull Observer<? super T> observer);
}
```

We see that in `ObservableSource.subscribe()` method parameter is called `observer`, so we see it as `observer->`.

**Conclusion**:
IDEA's suggestion is based on the parameter's name of the method of Functional interface you are implementing as lambda.

Comment: I added my screenshot in question... in my case it's `t ->`

Comment: My Code Completion Settings are the same

Comment: I guess the problem is in the RxJava library you are using, particular version 1.3. I've edited my answer, using `Observable` from RxJava2 will reflect right code completion.

Comment: Seems it is bacause of
`public interface Func1<T, R> extends Function {
    R call(T t);
}`

Comment: Yes, seems like that. In `RxJava2` parameter is called `observer`, so in code completion we see it as `observer`: 
`public interface ObservableSource<T> {
    void subscribe(@NonNull Observer<? super T> observer);
}`

Answer (score 4):

Actually Intellij helps you on the Java side but not (yet) on the Kotlin side.

The `subscriber`-parameter-name is derived from the generic type of the extended interface, i.e. `Subscriber` from  `interface OnSubscribe<T> extends Action1<Subscriber<? super T>>`.

On the Kotlin side however this mechanism isn't applied and so the code completion suggests you the parameter of the implementing function instead, which in this case is from `Action1#call(T t)`, so just `t`.

You can test that it uses the generic type information by just making a basic example:

```
class CustomObject {}
interface MyCustomConsumer extends Consumer<CustomObject> { }

static void test(MyCustomConsumer mcs) { }

public static void main(String[] args) {
     test( // <- place cursor here and start code completion and you should get "customObject"
```

Note that for some types it adapts the naming, e.g. `String` becomes `s` and the other boxed types (`Long`, `Integer`, etc.) are preceded by an `a` (e.g. `aLong`; of course, otherwise you would use a reserved word).

If you are curious what's happening in the source code there, you might want to go through [Intellij community source code](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community) or for Android Studio you may want to go through [Building Android Studio](http://tools.android.com/build/studio) first.

EDIT: I should have added the Kotlin plugin code instead ;-) if you want to improve the completion suggestions for Kotlin you may want to have a look at [JetBrains/kotlin/idea/idea-completion](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/tree/master/idea/idea-completion/src/org/jetbrains/kotlin/idea/completion). In addition [JetBrains/kotlin/idea/src](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/tree/master/idea/src/org/jetbrains/kotlin/idea) might also be worth a look and you probably end up looking at all of the [JetBrains/kotlin/idea-packages](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/tree/master/idea) ;-)